# swiper.min.js scrollbar: Force scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar, swiper.js

I have used swiper.min.js in my [website](http://demo.wehubs.com/sample_demo/). However, I need a scrollbar to appear on the right side of my website, because majority of my target audience will be using laptops without mousewheel, and it will be impossible for them to scroll without difficulty.

I already tried adding the following:

```
<div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
```

and instantiating it as follows from my HTML file:

```
 <script>
   var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
     scrollbar: {
       el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
       hide: true,
     },
   });
 </script>
```

None of this works. A scrollbar momentarily appears and it instantly disappears. I have checked swiper.min.js documentation, but it doesn't work. How can I force a scrollbar with proper scroll functionality on my website?

Comment: how about removing hide:true?

Comment: tried but no change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not the intended solution, but it fixes your issue**. Basically what your swiper setup does is, it adds `overflow:hidden` to your `.swiper-container` css class right after the initiation.

I'm sure there must be a way to prevent this from happening but if you cant figure it out this will help for sure (allthough again, this is not the intended solution):

Add the folowing snipped to your css:

```
.swiper-container {
     overflow: auto !important;
}
```

The `!important` makes sure, that swiper cannot override it via JQuery.

Comment: Now the scrollbar appeared, as you an see in the website demo.wehubs.com/sample_demo, but cannot seem to use the scrollbar. I can't click and drag the scrollbar. Any idea?

Comment: I dont see the scroll bar at all and I also dont see the css property being added

Comment: It appears here.. could you please load the url in incognito.

Comment: I see what you mean. Can you post the full swiper code and the full initiation code in a fiddle so i can try to fix it?